# How do I tell django to use --skip-secure-auth when connecting to mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, django

My django setup needs to connect to a mysql backend. I am getting the following error:

```
(2049, "Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)")
```

Googling around tells my that that error means I need to use the ' --skip-secure-auth' command line switch. I can not find any way to get django to use this switch, or it's equivalent.

How can I do that? (or alternately what is the real problem, if I am way off base.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `OPTIONS`?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'secure-auth': False,
        },
    }
}
```

sources:

[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DATABASES)
[mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_secure-auth)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I get a "TypeError: keywords must be strings" from the bowals of MySQLdb

Comment: maybe like this: `'secure-auth': 'False'` ?

Comment: The problem turned out to be that we are using a custom hacked version of MySQL and no one told me.